# Why Codeigniter3.0's url can't be blank after doamin name?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm corrently develop webs application for selling products online by using Codeigniter and upgrade from Ci2.2.1 to CI3.0.
However I've meet an errors **404 Page Not Found** when I enter domain name on url not yet called any controller by hoped **default_controller** will load instead of type my main controller.

**Notes: It is working on Ci2.2.1 and it stop work when upgrade to CI3.0.**

*It is working if I type any characters or any Controller after domain name(**http://localhost/Ecom3/sometroller**) But it is coudn't call default_controller and keep empty or blank after domain (http://localhost/Ecom3/).*

**Errors log:** *ERROR - 2015-04-24 03:48:57 --> 404 Page Not Found: /index*

Please check my webs structure below:

**Main**->**Main_controller**->**MY_controller**->**CI_Controller** 
My purpose to make it easy to controller the templates.

[image]

In MY_controller I've use __autoload() function

```
function __autoload($class){
    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $class .'.php'))
        {
            include_once $file;
        }
    }
}
```

**And I have confige route as below**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main/Main";
$route['(:any)'] = 'main/main/index/$1';
$route['c'] = 'cat/cat/index/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

The problem:
My url can't be blank after I type domain or after forword slash as below image

[image]

Please help

Comment: Are your controllers capitalized? You may have to set it in routes.php also

Comment: That it, Because I try to read CI3 userguide3 and I'm really carefully to do it

Comment: I think if name of controller is not Capitalized when I type controller it will not work but this cause if i type any character it will wok

Comment: Try with renaming `MY_controller.php` to `MY_Controller.php`.

Comment: Change it already but still the same

Comment: Codeigniter3.0 doesn't allow me to create directory inside controller as my needed
Controller/Main/Main.php and **$route['default_controller'] = "Main/Main";**
It is will work if I used this directory. WHY
controller/Main.php and **$route['default_controller'] = "Main";** 
WHY?

Comment: In codeigniter 3.0 you cannot use sub directories in default_controller that's the only down side of CI3 in CI2 you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try your code and get 404 when Main.php in your controller place inside `controller/main` folder. but when im move Main.php into `controller` folder, default controller to Main has working. then im try to debuging and see:

```
// Is the method being specified?
        if (sscanf($this->default_controller, '%[^/]/%s', $class, $method) !== 2)
        {
            $method = 'index';
        }
```

in core/Router.php

thats mean codeigniter3 are not allowed you to set default_controller in sub folder. you must put default_controller in `app/controller/` to make it works.

in config/router.php
change this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main/Main";
```

TO:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "Main";
```

then move your controller file :

`app/controller/main/Main.php`

TO

```
app/controller/Main.php
```

Comment: This is work for me.But it is not make sent because why permit like this